Convert smallint into yyyy
I have  a table1 with 20 columns one of which is year column as smallint in the format of YYYY.
I want to insert it into table2 with year column as Datetime  but as date format YYYY.
insert into table2
     (Year)
Select 
     CONVERT(datetime,convert(varchar(10),year))
from table1

However it did not work with the error

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any suggestions?

"with year column as Datetime but as date format YYYY." A datetime can't be just stored as a year; a datetime is made up of a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and milliseconds (accurate tom 1/300th of a second). If you just want to store the year, then smallint is the most appropriate data type. If you want to store a full date, but only display the year, that's an application matter.

type DateTime cannot not only by year (yyyy), it needs a full date, so what do you want for month and day and minute and hour and second and millisecond ?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Numbers an dates have no format, they're binary values. You can't just convert a single number to a date either - is that a year, month, day? The server can't guess. If you have the year, use DATEFROMPARTS or DATETIMEFROMPARTS to construct a date or datetime

Thank you for the response, however this is what is happening:
I ran:
Select
DATEFROMPARTS(year,1,1)
From table1
or
Select
DateTimeFromParts (year,1,1,0,0,0,0)
From table1
both show the results briefly, then an error appears:
Der date-Datentyp kann nicht erstellt werden, weil einige Argumente über ungültige Werte verfügen.
"The date data type cannot be created because some arguments have invalid values."

@AlexJ you probably have some strange year values. See SELECT MIN(year), MAX(year) from yourtable . Datetime have limits on how small and large the date can be

Yes there were negative numbers and I have solved it. Thank you for your time

You want DateTimeFromParts():
insert into table2
     (Year)
Select 
     DateTimeFromParts(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
from table1

There's also DateFromParts() if you just need a date value (as well as options for DateTime2, DateTimeOffset, and SmallDateTime), but as the question states you have a DateTime column we'll make sure the types match cleanly.
Do NOT use strings for this. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, using strings tends to be much slower and more error-prone than you'd want or expect, with lots of subtle "gotchas".

You should probably keep the DATEFROMPARTS example too. I suspect the OP doesn't know about the date type or how useful it can be

@PanagiotisKanavos I updated to cover it.

Thank you for the response, however this is what is happening:
I ran:
Select
DATEFROMPARTS(year,1,1)
From table1
or
Select
DateTimeFromParts (year,1,1,0,0,0,0)
From table1
both show the results briefly, then an error appears:
Der date-Datentyp kann nicht erstellt werden, weil einige Argumente über ungültige Werte verfügen.
"The date data type cannot be created because some arguments have invalid values."

@AlexJ This means you have data in the year column that does not map to a valid year. Any negative numbers? NULL values? 0s?

you nailed it, there were negative numbers and I have excluded these in the query. thank you. I will accept it as solution

You need to provide the day and month for that conversion to work. try something like this:
declare @table1 table([year] smallint)
insert into @table1(year) values(2024),(2016),(2015),(2023)

Select 
     CONVERT(datetime,convert(varchar(10),year)+'-01-01')
from @table1


Going through a string is almost always the wrong way to do this. This is doubly true in this case, because the code isn't even using the correct string format. For historical reasons, date-only literals in SQL Server should use an unseparated format with no - dashes.

datetime is affected by the DATEFIRST setting. Using DATEFROMPARTS removes any ambiguity

+ '0101' would've been better since it's unambiguous format
